# How to submit a HTML5 canvas as an image to django server

Tags: javascript, django, python-3.x, html5-canvas

I have created a Canvas which can be drawn upon by the user. Now after drawing is done and as i hit the submit button i want it to reach the server in django. I can not figure out the javascript behind this and how to access it in django's views. What is the way of doing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to submit html5 canvas as part of form post?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11708154/5223757)

Comment: You should just be able to get JavaScript triggered on the `click` event of the button to send the data with a callback from `toBlob` and `XMLHttpRequest`, as described in the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a lot of ways to do this.

One which is:
Assuming the images on canvas is all from the same origin, you can always call

```
const canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
const imageUri=canvas.toDataUrl()
```

and then you can append it to a form input and submit to the backend just like you would for normal form

Comment: Use [toBlob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) instead

Comment: this worked..!! thanks for help.
<canvas id="canvas" height="300px" width="300px"></canvas>
 <form action="" method="POST" id="form1">
     {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="canvasData" id="my_hidden">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="save()">
        </form>
        <script>
            function save(){
                var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                document.getElementById('my_hidden').value = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');document.forms["form1"].submit();
            }            
        </script>

Comment: You are welcome @BhavyaChoubisa if my answer solved your question, click on the checkbox to accept it as an answer.